# How do i separate my siddhimanager based on context?

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-cep

I have a number of streams coming in and i use wso2 to evaluate these stream with rules . Some of these streams can be bundled together as they would be from the same organization . How can i separate my siddhi context based on these different organizations .

So basically what i am looking for is something like this .

siddhimanager.context("context1").defineStream(...)
siddhimanager.context("context2").defineStream(...)

Any help would be highly appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

SiddhiManager is associated with a single SiddhiContext. So For your use case, you can just use separate SiddhiManager instances for each organization. 
This is actually how the different execution plans and also multi-tenancy  has been implemented in WSO2 CEP.